# after append content and invoke function in jquery

Tags: jquery

there are data page:_data.cshtml

```
<table id="example1" class="display table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<a href="#" url="/data/index" save-data="default"> Save Changes </a>
```

there are container page

```
<div class=".mycontainer"></div>
```

when i load data in container page like this:

```
$('.mycontainer').append(data).on('click', '[save-data="default"]', function (event) {
    load(event);
});

function load(event) {
    var url = $(this).data("url");
}
```

question:
**url == undefined**

i hope the value url = "/data/index"

i can append the partial page(_data.page)

but i can not get the value.

please give me some point ,thanks!

Comment: `<div class=".mycontainer"></div>` There should *not* be a full stop at the beginning of a class name in HTML.

Comment: Well, aside from the invalid classname you've added to your `<div />` (should be `mycontainer`, not `.mycontainer`), the issue is that within your `load()` function, `this` no longer refers to the `click` event's target element.

Comment: Where is the `data-winter-url` attribute in the HTML?

Comment: this is asp.net mvc ,there a controller named _data,and the _data.cshtml is the partial view with the controller ,and the append is $post submit.

Comment: data-winter-url is error code ,I have corrected this error. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to

```
$('.mycontainer').append(data).on('click', '[save-data="default"]', load);
```

Now without the anonymous function the arguments and `this` context will be correct

---

Also seems to be a typo in class name in html that shouldn't have a dot in it